# Best way to plot a 2D square lattice of atoms in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, networkx, physics

Summary of the problem:
I'm working on a Physics problem and I want to plot a 2D lattice of atoms, where the nodes have been connected using arrows as shown here [2D lattice figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YK8M.png).

What I've tried:
I've tried using [grid_2d_graph](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.generators.classic.grid_2d_graph.html#networkx.generators.classic.grid_2d_graph) from NetworkX, taking help from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33168699/remove-rotation-effect-when-drawing-a-square-grid-of-mxm-nodes-in-networkx-using) but wasn't able to get it to work as I wanted it to.  The code I used was as follows:

```
G = nx.grid_2d_graph(4,4)
pos = dict( (n, n) for n in G.nodes() )
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

This produced the following [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8fsJ.png), which wasn't exactly what I had in mind.

Comment: And what determines the direction of the arrows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simplistic approach using `matplotlib`'s `arrow`. It requires, that the grid (graph) is represented as a dictionary where the keys are point (node) coordinates on the grid and the values are neighbouring points to which an *outgoing* arrow (edge) should be drawn. When the size of your grid changes, you will probably need to play around with `w`, `h` and such to control the size of the plotted elements.

```py
grid = {  # point(x, y), outgoing connections [points] 
    (0, 0): [(0, 1), (1, 0)],
    (0, 1): [],
    (1, 0): [],
    (1, 1): [(1, 0), (0, 1)]
}

w = 0.005  # Errorwidth
h = 0.05   # Errorhead width

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for point, connections in grid.items():
    for outgoing in connections:
        dx = outgoing[0] - point[0]
        dy = outgoing[1] - point[1]
        ax.arrow(point[0], point[1],
                 dx / 2, dy / 2,
                 width=w, head_width=h,
                 facecolor="k",
                 zorder=0)
        ax.arrow(point[0] + dx / 2,
                 point[1] + dy / 2,
                 dx / 2, dy / 2,
                 width=w, head_width=0,
                 facecolor="k",
                 zorder=0)
    ax.plot(*point,
            marker="o", markersize=10, markeredgecolor="k",
            markerfacecolor="red",
            zorder=1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to use quiver plots when I came up on Jan's answer. I've modified his code to work with quiver plots

```
def plot_vector(p1,p2):
    p1 = np.array(p1)
    p2 = np.array(p2)
    dp = p2-p1
    plt.quiver(p1[0], p1[1], dp[0], dp[1],angles='xy', scale_units='xy', scale=1, headwidth = 5, headlength = 7)


grid = {  # point(x, y), outgoing connections [points] 
    (0, 0): [(0, 1), (1, 0)],
    (0, 1): [],
    (1, 0): [],
    (1, 1): [(1, 0), (0, 1)]
}


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for point, connections in grid.items():
    for outgoing in connections:
        plot_vector(point,outgoing)
    plt.plot(*point,
            marker="o", markersize=10, markeredgecolor="k",
            markerfacecolor="red",
            zorder=1)
plt.show()
```

[image: Resultant Plot]