# Python and Networkx: Retrieve Node Label Number and Compare it to a CSV Value

Tags: python, pandas, ubuntu, matrix, networkx

I have a simple **Python** and **Networkx** code that plots a 2D graph along with the node label numbers and edges (**edges are irrelevant in my case**, so it would be nice if I can somehow remove them):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

csv_io = pd.read_csv('matrix101.csv', index_col=[0])
#csv_list = csv_io.values.tolist()

N = 5
G = nx.grid_2d_graph(N,N)
pos = dict( (n, n) for n in G.nodes() )
labels = dict( ((i, j), i + 1 + (N-1-j) * N ) for i, j in G.nodes() )

nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos, labels=labels, node_color='red')
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

The output is (with node colour red):

[image: Figure-1]

I wish to **retrieve the node numbers from the 2D graph** and **compare them** to values in a **CSV matrix which is similar but slightly modified**... for example, with the following '**X**' patterns (let's call it "**matrix101.csv**" from the code above):

```
1   2   3   4   5
X   7   8   9   10
X   12  13  14  15
16  17  X   19  20
21  22  X   24  25
```

So basically, when I input the CSV file "**matrix101.csv**" into the code, the CSV node values must be compared and the values with '**X**' should indicate a **different colour** in the original 2D graph... that is, like a mismatch:

[image: Figure-2]

I use **Pandas** to read the CSV file but that's about it and I've hit a roadblock and unable to proceed further.
Any ideas on how I can realize this idea of comparing both matrices?
Thanks in advance!

P.S. Code snippet borrowed from this question:
[Remove rotation effect when drawing a square grid of MxM nodes in networkx using grid_2d_graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33168699/remove-rotation-effect-when-drawing-a-square-grid-of-mxm-nodes-in-networkx-using)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to create color list that you then pass to `node_color=` parameter:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("matrix101.csv", index_col=None, header=None, sep=r"\s+", dtype=str)

N = 5
G = nx.grid_2d_graph(N, N)
pos = dict((n, n) for n in G.nodes())

colors = [
    "red" if df.loc[N - 1 - j, i] == str(i + 1 + (N - 1 - j) * N) else "green"
    for i, j in G.nodes()
]
# OR:
# colors = ["red" if df.loc[N - 1 - j, i] != "X" else "green" for i, j in G.nodes()]

labels = dict(((i, j), i + 1 + (N - 1 - j) * N) for i, j in G.nodes())

nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos, labels=labels, node_color=colors)
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

Shows:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer... however, I'm getting this annoying error: 
`raise KeyError(key) from err` , `KeyError: 0` , and I've no clue what is causing this... any idea what could be wrong? 
By the way, I was able to remove the edges with this: `G.remove_edges_from(G.edges())`

Comment: @user136819 Make sure when you load the CSV you specify `header=None` and `index_col=None`. You want to have rows and columns numbered from `0`

Comment: Already accepted your answer as it solved my purpose! :-)