# Python and Networkx: Randomly Highlight Nodes by ignoring Patterns in CSV files

Tags: python, pandas, ubuntu, matrix, networkx

I have **4 CSV files**, with slightly different '**X**' matrix patterns each.
The '**X**' patterns in each of the matrices vary from 1 to **N**-1 , with **N** marking the size of the matrix - **(5,5)** in this case:

```
pattern-1.csv        |   pattern-2.csv        |   pattern-3.csv        |   pattern-4.csv
                     |                        |                        |
1   2   3   4   5    |   1   2   3   X   X    |   1   2   3   4   5    |   X   2   3   4   5
X   7   8   9   10   |   6   7   8   9   X    |   6   7   X   9   10   |   6   X   8   9   10
X   12  13  14  15   |   13  12  13  14  15   |   7   12  X   14  15   |   7   12  13  14  15
16  17  X   19  20   |   16  17  18  19  20   |   16  17  X   19  20   |   16  17  14  19  20
21  22  X   24  25   |   21  22  23  24  25   |   21  22  X   24  25   |   21  22  23  24  25
```

I wish to generate **(N,N)** graphs that **randomly highlight** some nodes from min 1 to max **N**-1 (by **highlight** I mean a different colour for the nodes). And with **each random run / iteration**, the **total sum** of the labels of the highlighted nodes should be within a range 40 to 80 (for example, sum of 3 randomly highlighted nodes **12** + **15** + **20** = 47 , and so on...).

However, the highlighted nodes in the generated graphs **SHOULD NOT** match any of the '**X**' patterns in the above 4 CSV files.
Basically, the code should take the 4 CSV files as a dataset and generate such graphs and also take the above mentioned into consideration... eventually there would be more CSV files for the dataset.

I have a simple Python code that does the opposite of what I wish to achieve with a single CSV file:

```
from tabulate import tabulate
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

N = 5
G = nx.grid_2d_graph(N,N)

df = pd.read_csv('pattern-1.csv', index_col=None, header=None, dtype=str)

pos = dict( (n,n) for n in G.nodes() )

colors = [ "red" if df.loc[N - 1 - j, i] != "X" else "green" for i, j in G.nodes() ]

labels = dict( ((i,j), i + 1 + (N - 1 - j) * N) for i,j in G.nodes() )

print(tabulate(df, showindex=False, tablefmt="plain"))
#print("Sum of the nodes: " ???)

G.remove_edges_from(G.edges())
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos, labels=labels, node_color=colors)
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

Output of the above:

[image: Figure-1]

Any ideas on how I can achieve these goals?
Also, does it make sense to turn the individual patterns in the 4 CSV files into lists and put them into a single CSV file for simplicity?
If yes, then how would the code look like?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. This is an extension of my previous question here:
[Python and Networkx: Retrieve Node Label Number and Compare it to a CSV Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77345663/python-and-networkx-retrieve-node-label-number-and-compare-it-to-a-csv-value)
Thanks again to @AndrejKesely

**EDIT**:

Although I still seek help with the part of **random highlighting** of nodes that **shouldn't** match the '**X**' patterns in the matrices... I was able to figure out how to use the total sum within a range:

```
import random
pick = random.sample(range(1,N*N), N-1)
r = range(40,80)
if sum(pick) in r:
  print("True: ", sum(pick))
else:
  print("False: ", sum(pick))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it with Python standard library's [random](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0s7i1.png) and [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#module-itertools) modules:

```py
import random
from itertools import combinations

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        1: [1, "X", "X", 16, 21],
        2: [2, 7, 12, 17, 22],
        3: [3, 8, 13, "X", "X"],
        4: [4, 9, 14, 19, 24],
        5: [5, 10, 15, 20, 25],
    }
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        1: [1, 6, 13, 16, 21],
        2: [2, 7, 12, 17, 22],
        3: [3, 8, 13, 18, 23],
        4: ["X", 9, 14, 19, 24],
        5: ["X", "X", 15, 20, 25],
    }
)
```

```py
N = 5
MIN_NUM_OF_HIGHLIGHTED_NODES = 1
MIN_RANGE = 40
MAX_RANGE = 80

dfs = (df1, df2)

x_labels = [
    i + 1
    for df in dfs
    for i, v in enumerate(item for row in df.to_numpy() for item in row)
    if v == "X"
]

free_labels = [i for i in range(N * N + 1) if i not in x_labels]

# Check that there is at least possible combination of nodes
# that will match the constraints (otherwise, the while-loop
# will never end)
max_num_of_highlighted_nodes = 0
for i in range(len(free_labels) + 1):
    for combination in combinations(free_labels, i):
        if MIN_RANGE <= sum(combination) <= MAX_RANGE:
            max_num_of_highlighted_nodes = N * N - len(x_labels)
            break

# randomly highlight in green some nodes from min 1 to max N-1
# total sum of the labels of the highlighted nodes should be within MIN and MAX range
while True:
    if not max_num_of_highlighted_nodes:
        nodes_to_highlight = []
        break
    nodes_to_highlight = random.sample(
        range(MIN_NUM_OF_HIGHLIGHTED_NODES, max_num_of_highlighted_nodes + 1),
        k=random.randint(MIN_NUM_OF_HIGHLIGHTED_NODES, max_num_of_highlighted_nodes),
    )
    if (not set(nodes_to_highlight).intersection(x_labels)) and (
        MIN_RANGE <= sum(nodes_to_highlight) <= MAX_RANGE
    ):
        break

G = nx.grid_2d_graph(N, N)
G.remove_edges_from(G.edges())

pos = {n: n for n in G.nodes()}
labels = {(i, j): i + 1 + (N - 1 - j) * N for i, j in G.nodes()}

# green nodes in the generated graph SHOULD NOT match any of the 'X' red nodes
colors = [
    "green" if label in nodes_to_highlight else "white" for label in labels.values()
]
colors = [
    "red" if label in x_labels else color
    for color, label in zip(colors, labels.values())
]

nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos, labels=labels, node_color=colors)
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

Each time the above cell is run in a Jupyter notebook, you will get a random output matching the given constraints:

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

And so on.

Comment: firstly, thanks for answering. I notice that in your answer, you take 1 pattern (6, 11, 18, 23) as an example for each iteration/run... Is it possible to include ALL the patterns i.e., 1, 2, 3, 4 into each iteration/run? If yes, then how?  
(FYI, my final goal is to eliminate any "potential" or "co-incidental" patterns that are generated randomly and they shouldn't match the original pattern dataset 1, 2, 3, 4, but by using the original pattern dataset as an example - perhaps like in machine learning techniques) :)

Comment: *is it possible to take into consideration ALL the patterns i.e., 1, 2, 3, 4 ...

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. What do you mean by 1, 2, 3, 4? Pattern-1.csv, Pattern-2.csv, etc.? Also, if you take all X marks at once, what will be left for green marks? Cheers.

Comment: Exactly, pattern-1.csv, pattern-2.csv etc... - and to answer your other question: the analogy here is, that the nodes in "red" (ALL choices from given _example_ dataset) are "human errors/patterns chosen by humans"... and the code should still be able to eliminate ALL these "potential human choices/patterns" in each iteration/run by considering the entire dataset lists and still be able to generate enough random "green" node choices (perhaps an error margin of 1 or 2 node match (red and green) is still okay)... I hope this helps? :)

Comment: Extending the previous comment: eventually, there will be more combinations of "potential human choices/patterns" that will be added to the given dataset as individual lists and code needs to perform "human pattern elimination" by considering ALL "human choices" in every single iteration/run and still be able to generate enough random "green" nodes, perhaps also with above mentioned error margin as a "max tolerance level" :-)

Comment: I've updated my answer in order to deal with several dataframes, to the best of my understanding of your use case. Cheers.

Comment: thank you, I've incorporated some of the parts... however, I'm still stuck with the whole pattern recognition thing... I've asked a very similar question in URL below, referencing your answers and explaining in more detail what I wish to achieve, so perhaps this will help more in understanding my problems and goals:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77368418/python-networkx-generate-lists-with-random-unique-numbers-outside-a-given-datas