# Python Networkx: Generate lists with random unique numbers outside a given dataset pattern

Tags: python, list, random, networkx

**Updating the question**:

I have the following lists (a simple, extendable dataset in a CSV file). Let's consider them as "potential human choices/patterns". Some lists contain consecutive, non-repetitive integer numbers and others contain non-repetitive unique numbers that follow a pattern which represent what "a human would choose":

```
sample-list-1.csv

N = 5

list1 = [1,  2,  3,  4,  5]
list2 = [2,  3,  4,  5,  6]
list3 = [7,  8,  9, 10, 11]
list4 = [8,  9, 10, 11, 12]
list5 = [1,  7, 13, 19, 25]
list6 = [7, 13, 19, 25, 31]
list7 = [2,  8, 14, 20, 26]
list8 = [8, 14, 20, 26, 32]
...
```

... and so on.
Each list is in a separate row and each number in the list is in a separate column in the CSV file - no headers or index.
At a closer look, the numbers in the lists may represent a matrix, which is totally correct, but with N+1... i.e, a 6x6 node matrix:

```
6 x 6 matrix

1   2   3   4   5   6
7   8   9   10  11  12
13  14  15  16  17  18
19  20  21  22  23  24
25  26  27  28  29  30
31  32  33  34  35  36
```

Here are visual representations of the matrix graph with some of the "human choice" patterns as yellow nodes:

[image: Figure-1]

... and so on.

My goal is to generate a new list (or lists) that contains 'N' non-consecutive, non-repetitive, unique/random numbers which are not similar to the "human" patterns as seen in the *sample-list-1.csv* dataset. The N numbers in the newly generated list(s) should, of course, be among the 36 numbers from the matrix.
For example, the 'N' green nodes below are from randomly generated lists:

[image: Figure-2]

An error margin/tolerance of maximum 2 consecutive green/yellow numbers in a row or 2 continuous green/yellow numbers (column-wise) or 1 number from the "human" pattern can also be taken into consideration,  but the other numbers in the generated list should match the given constraints.
For example, random green nodes and the "error margin/error tolerance" nodes marked in blue:

[image: Figure-3]

So far, I'm able to create the graphs, import the CSV file and able to generate a list containing random, non-repetitive numbers with the simple code:

```
import random
import csv
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

N = 5
G = nx.grid_2d_graph(6,6)
pick = random.sample(range(1, (N*N)+1), N)
#print("pick:", pick)

with open('sample-list-1.csv', newline = '') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    csvdata = list(reader)

csvdata_list = [int(x) for x in csvdata[2]]
#print("csvdata_list:", csvdata_list)

for n in pick:
    for i in csvdata_list:
        if n == i:
            print("n=", n, "i=", i)

pos = {n: n for n in G.nodes()}
labels = {(i, j): i + 1 + (N - 1 - j) * N for i, j in G.nodes()}
colors = [ "green" if label in pick else "red" for label in labels.values() ]
colors = [ "yellow" if label in csvdata_list else color for color, label in zip(colors, labels.values()) ]

nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos, labels=labels, node_color=colors)
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

And I'm able to do some simple comparisons with the original Dataset and the random number list `pick` using the loops.
However, my current method only iterates through a single list/pattern at a time, and I wish to iterate through ALL the lists and their patterns from the CSV in every iteration/run **at once**, to create uniqueness in the newly generated lists/nodes.

The main idea is to eliminate ANY possibility of a "human" pattern forming in the newly generated list/nodes, as I've seen that even a random number generator code can still sometimes create such lists with "human" patterns (as seen in the given dataset).
Just an example of *iterating through ALL possibilities at once in a single run* of a "human" pattern not forming in the newly generated list/nodes (with error margin of 2 nodes column-wise **25** and **31**):

[image: Figure-4]

Any ideas on how I can achieve these goals with the given constraints and the original dataset?

Final note:
As @JonSG pointed out:
How do you intend to identify a "human looking" pattern from a random pattern? - the answer is simple:
The random pattern (i.e., the newly generated random pattern) should simply not match (and when considering the error margin, at least close to not matching) anything that a human would choose, let's say out of laziness or impatience or no creativity in choosing any 'N' numbers from given 6x6 numbers, etc...

I hope that with this update, the question is more precise.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by _pattern_ ? In the example, it looks like an AP with a difference of 6 - do you mean the _pattern_ can only be an Arithmetic Progression of some kind?

Comment: Your **matrix** idea doesn't make any sense at all to me, much less totally correct. I see no **random** numbers in your example dataset either. Please clarify what you're trying to achieve and examples that back your explanation.

Comment: @Woodford : I've added an edit in the question

Comment: @Mortz : the original Dataset lists each have patterns - perhaps yes, like a progression. Hence, I added the matrix as an example to show these patterns. I've added an edit section in the original question

Comment: @Mortz : I've now updated the question again with more details explaining what I wish to achieve. I hope this helps :)

Comment: @Woodford : I've now updated the question again with more details explaining what I wish to achieve. I hope this helps :)

Comment: Voted to reopen. Thanks for the updates.

Comment: @Woodford : thanks for the vote - I've added a final note in the question... I hope that this will finally clear any or every doubt about the question :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want true random sets, then forcing it to avoid a pattern is also creating a less rigid pattern.

The most random way is to allow it to choose completely at random for each index. If you want no duplicates simply use a sampling method without replacement.

An easy way to reuse all the values in your existing set in a random order would be to use `random.shuffle()`

```
new_list=csvdata_list
random.shuffle(new_list)
```

The thing to note, is that random shuffle works in-place, meaning it rearranges your current list, so you need to copy the list then shuffle it. This way no duplicates, all your numbers and true randomness.

You could always create a function that checks for more than two in a row removes the third in a series and extends the list with some rules that prevent it from making another series, but it reduces the random factor some.

If the goal is randomness, then not constraining is key.

If you need it to have no consecutive values or progressions, then that is a different criteria, but will contradict true randomness, because in a truly random situation series and progressions could occur. The key is that they would most certainly be localized.

Comment: please check the EDIT section in the question if it helps :)

Comment: I appreciate that you added more, but really you are asking someone not to give you help debugging something or unpacking logic. You are asking someone to write an algorithm you need. That is not really the point of stack overflow

Comment: thanks for pointing this out, but I'm actually asking for help with just 1 last step where I've hit a roadblock and unable to proceed... I already have an algorithm in mind, but I'm not able to produce it into a refined code as I'm still a novice in Python... I've updated the question again, I hope that it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to employ a number of "tricks" here:

- flatten a matrix: `[item for row in rows for item in row]`
- count of true values in a list: `sum(bool(item) for item in items)`:
- transpose a matrix: `list(zip(*matrix))`
- take list items in consecutive pairs: `zip(items, items[1:])`
- chunk a list: `[items[i:i+size] for i in range(0, len(items), size)]`

With these in hand, I would create two helper functions.

**One to scramble the items in our matrix:**

```py
def scramble(data):
    column_count = len(data[0])
    items = [item for row in data for item in row]
    random.shuffle(items)

    return [
        items[index: index + column_count]
        for index
        in range(0, len(items), column_count)
    ]
```

**The second to test if a row has fewer than some number of consecutive values.**

```py
def is_valid_row(row, max_consecutives=0):
    consecutive_count = sum(abs(a - b) <= 1 for a, b in zip(row, row[1:]))
    return consecutive_count <= max_consecutives
```

Now we can try to continually generate candidate matrixes until a good one is found. Of course you could add a counter here to give up after some number of failures if you wanted:

```
data = [
    [1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
    [2,  3,  4,  5,  6],
    [1,  7, 13, 19, 25],
    [7, 13, 19, 25, 31],
]

i = 0
while True:
    i += 1
    print(f"Testing Candidate Matrix: {i}", end="\r", flush=True)

    candidate = scramble(data)
    if all(is_valid_row(row) for row in candidate):
        if all(is_valid_row(row) for row in zip(*candidate)):
            print()
            break

print("Candidate found:")
for row in candidate:
    print(f"\t{row}")
```

That should give you something like:

```
Testing Candidate Matrix: 511
Candidate found:
        [2, 31, 25, 13, 2]
        [19, 4, 1, 3, 7]
        [3, 13, 5, 7, 4]
        [19, 5, 25, 1, 6]
```

Comment: firstly, thanks for answering. My goal is not to generate a new matrix, but just to generate a new list that isn't similar to the original Dataset lists... the thing is, that even with randomly generated data, sometimes even the random data generates numbers in the so called "patterns" I mentioned in the question. I've added an EDIT in the original question, so I hope this would help :)

Comment: IF the original list is not important and you just want a matrix of numbers from 1 to 36, then in `scramble()` use `items = [random.randint(1,36) for _ in range(36)`

Comment: as others have pointed out that they've not been able to make sense of the original question, I've updated it again with new details... I hope that this helps :)

Comment: How do you intend to identify a "human looking" pattern from a random pattern?

Comment: The random pattern (i.e., the newly generated random pattern) should simply not match (or at least close to not matching, considering the error margin) anything that a human would choose, let's say out of laziness or impatience or no creativity in choosing any 'N' numbers from given 6x6 numbers. Unfortunately, I need to take ALL such possibilities into consideration :/