# Python: Generate new Lists with Random Unique Numbers using a given Dataset Progression

Tags: python, list, csv, iteration

I have the following lists (as a dataset in a CSV file). Some lists contain consecutive, non-repetitive integer numbers and others contain non-repetitive integer numbers.
If we observe, there is a certain progression (or pattern) to the numbers in each of the lists and each list is bound to 5 numbers/elements '**N**':

```
sample-list-1.csv

N = 5

list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]       |  list9 = [25, 26, 27, 28, 29]   |  list17 = [3, 9, 15, 21, 27]
list2 = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]       |  list10 = [26, 27, 28, 29, 30]  |  list18 = [9, 15, 21, 27, 33]
list3 = [7, 8, 9, 10, 11]     |  list11 = [31, 32, 33, 34, 35]  |  list19 = [4, 10, 16, 22, 28]
list4 = [8, 9, 10, 11, 12]    |  list12 = [32, 33, 34, 35, 36]  |  list20 = [10, 16, 22, 28, 34]
list5 = [13, 14, 15, 16, 17]  |  list13 = [1, 7, 13, 19, 25]    |  list21 = [5, 11, 17, 23, 29]
list6 = [14, 15, 16, 17, 18]  |  list14 = [7, 13, 19, 25, 31]   |  list22 = [11, 17, 23, 29, 35]
list7 = [19, 20, 21, 22, 23]  |  list15 = [2, 8, 14, 20, 26]    |  list23 = [6, 12, 18, 24, 30]
list8 = [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]  |  list16 = [8, 14, 20, 26, 32]   |  list24 = [12, 18, 24, 30, 36]
```

For example, the progression/pattern for the numbers in *list1* is `[number+1, etc.]` and the progression/pattern for *list16* is `[number+6, etc.]` and so on.

In the CSV file itself, each list is in a separate row and each number in the list is in a separate column - with no headers or index. At a closer look, the numbers in the lists may represent a matrix, which is totally correct, but with N+1... i.e, a 6x6 matrix:

```
6 x 6 matrix

1   2   3   4   5   6
7   8   9   10  11  12
13  14  15  16  17  18
19  20  21  22  23  24
25  26  27  28  29  30
31  32  33  34  35  36
```

For simplicity sake, let's ignore the matrix as it's are not relevant to our case.

Keeping the given dataset lists in mind:
**My goal** is just to generate a new list (or lists) that contains 5 non-consecutive, non-repetitive, unique/random numbers which do not follow any of the progressions/patterns as seen in the *sample-list-1.csv* dataset lists.
The 5 random numbers in the newly generated list(s) should be in range from 1 to 36 numbers (as seen in the matrix).
For example, the newly generated list(s) should look similar to the following:

```
list_new = [1, 6, 17, 23, 33] (or)
list_new = [8, 22, 24, 34, 36] (or)
list_new = [10, 11, 20, 32, 35] ...
```

... and so on.
An error margin/tolerance of maximum 2 consecutive numbers in a row (number+1) or 2 continuous numbers (number+6) can be taken into consideration, but the other numbers in the generated list should be totally random and also match the given constraints (i.e., no progressions).
For example, the new lists with error margins/tolerance:

```
list_new = [1, 2, 17, 23, 33] (or)   -->  2 random generated elements match in list1
list_new = [2, 9, 15, 32, 36] (or)   -->  2 random generated elements match in list17/18
list_new = [5, 16, 22, 23, 34] ...   -->  2 random generated elements match in list19/20 & list7/8
```

The idea is to eliminate ANY possibility of the progression/pattern forming in the newly generated list, because I've observed that even a random number generator code can still sometimes generate numbers in a "**progression**" as seen in the given dataset lists, such as:

```
not_desired = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6] (or)        -->  all random generated elements match in list2 and 4 in list1
not_desired = [8, 9, 10, 34, 36] (or)     -->  3 random generated elements match in list3/4
not_desired = [11, 17, 23, 29, 32] ...    -->  4 random generated elements match in list21/22
```

The **order** of the elements in the new generated list(s) doesn't matter.
For the moment, I can iterate through a single list at a time from the dataset and generate a new list...

But I mainly wish to generate a new list by **iterating through ALL the lists from the dataset in one go** at every single run of the code (with each run generating a newer, random list)...
This can be expressed as a rough algorithm similar to:

```
----- Run-1 -----
# iterate through lists 1 to 24 in one go #
-->
# generate a new list with random numbers that matches given constraints #

----- Run-2 -----
# iterate through lists 1 to 24 in one go #
-->
# generate a new list with random numbers that matches given constraints #

... and so on
```

I have the following code snippet and would appreciate any help in reaching the goal:

```
import random
import csv

pick = random.sample(range(1, 37), 5)    # generate the new random number list
#print("pick:", pick)

with open('sample-list-1.csv', newline = '') as f:    # open the csv file to read the 24 lists
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    csvdata = list(reader)

csvdata_list = [int(x) for x in csvdata[2]]   # iterating one list at a time - which is time consuming!
#print("csvdata_list:", csvdata_list)

for n in pick:
    for i in csvdata_list:
        if n == i:
            print("n=", n, "i=", i)    # making a simple comparison

### How to iterate through ALL the dataset lists at once? ###
```

If any more details are needed, please comment and I will update the question.
Thanks in advance!

P.S. This question is a little simplified version of the question I asked here:
[Python Networkx: Generate lists with random unique numbers outside a given dataset pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77368418/python-networkx-generate-lists-with-random-unique-numbers-outside-a-given-datas)

Answer (score 0):

I eventually managed to settle for a workaround and answering my own question.
The workaround is that I check if the new generated list exists in the given dataset list.
If not, then the logic continues.